# UWP Media Capture Not Recording Video through WebCam

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, webcam

I am trying to develop a UWP app where I need to record video via webcam. I have followed microsoft tutorial about it here but the problem is I am getting following error again and again and recording does not work.

**Error**

> "This object needs to be initialized before the requested operation
>   can be carried out.\r\nThis object needs to be initialized before the
>   requested operation can be carried out."

**Here is my code:**

```
int counter = 1;
                var myVideos = await Windows.Storage.StorageLibrary.GetLibraryAsync(Windows.Storage.KnownLibraryId.Videos);
                StorageFile file = await myVideos.SaveFolder.CreateFileAsync("survillance "+DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy")+"_"+counter+".wmv", CreationCollisionOption.GenerateUniqueName);

                try
                {
                    MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = null;
                    recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateWmv(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

                    _mediaRecording = await _mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile,file);
                    await _mediaRecording.StartAsync();


                    status.Text = "Video recording in progress...";


                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {

                    status.Text = "Failed to Capture...";
                    var msg = new MessageDialog(ex.Message, "Capturing Error").ShowAsync();
                }
```

Please help me in figuring out the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to call [MediaCapture.InitializeAsync()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br226599.aspx) before starting the capture.

```
MediaEncodingProfile recordProfile = MediaEncodingProfile.CreateMp4(VideoEncodingQuality.Auto);

_mediaCapture   = new MediaCapture();
_mediaCapture.InitializeAsync();

_mediaRecording = await _mediaCapture.PrepareLowLagRecordToStorageFileAsync(recordProfile,file);
await _mediaRecording.StartAsync();
```